# Disable MS Teams invitation mail via C#/Graph

Tags: c#, powershell, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I have a provisioning engine in C# that creats new MS Teams with MS Graph. Whenever a user is added to a Team (inside the Teams Client) he gets 2 invitation mails - one for the O365 Group and one for Teams itself.

The O365 Group Mail was disabled via custom Code (ResourceBehaviorOptions -> WelcomeEmailDisabled) taken from the PnP Core Unified Groups Utility:

```
class ExtendedO365Group : Microsoft.Graph.Group
{
    [JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore, PropertyName = "resourceBehaviorOptions")]
    public string[] ResourceBehaviorOptions { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("owners@odata.bind", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string[] OwnersODataBind { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("members@odata.bind", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string[] MembersODataBind { get; set; }
}

[...]

var newGroup = new ExtendedO365Group
{
    DisplayName = displayName,
    Description = description,
    MailNickname = mailNickname,
    MailEnabled = true,
    SecurityEnabled = false,
    Visibility = isPrivate == true ? "Private" : "Public",
    GroupTypes = new List<string> { "Unified" },
    ResourceBehaviorOptions = (disableWelcomeMail ? new string[] { "WelcomeEmailDisabled" } : null)
};
```

Inspired by this [Graph Issue](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/528).

And then later the Teams Team is added to the Group, but there seems to be no setting or property to disable mailing inside Teams.

I also know about this PowerShell Command, which does the same thing afaik

```
Set-UnifiedGroup -Identity "groupname" -UnifiedGroupWelcomeMessageEnable:$false
```

And tried to disable Mailing with

```
MailEnabled = false,
```

But all of this disables only the first mail, sent from the O365 Group with the Subject "User xy has added you to the Group yz" (roughly translated from German) and a link to the Outlook Group.
It does not disable the second mail from Teams "You have been added to a team in Microsoft Teams" with a link to open it in the Teams Client.

Is there some new Graph Property or C# command that will disable ALL invitation mails? If nothing else works I would try to integrate a PowerShell command if there is one that works.

EDIT: It really seems that this is a bug as seen in [this Uservoice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/35391220-make-unifiedgroupwelcomemessageenabled-work-for-te) and the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you've identified a gap in our existing APIs. I can confirm that we don't currently allow for suppressing "Added to team" emails from Microsoft Teams today both in the Desktop/Web Client as well as through Graph APIs.

We've noted this request and understand the scenario you are trying to design for. For now we'd like to ask you to share this feedback in this UserVoice to help us better prioritize adding this capability in a future release.

https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/35391220-make-unifiedgroupwelcomemessageenabled-work-for-te

Cheers
- Phecda Louie (Microsoft Teams PM)

Comment: While not giving a solution to my question, I accept it as the answer for now until this is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a unified group, you can disable welcome emails using the parameter "`UnifiedGroupWelcomeMessageEnabled`" - it's on by default.  So you can first create the unified groups and set that to $false, then convert those groups to teams using the Teams PowerShell cmdlet

```
New-Team -Group <GroupId of the group you just created>
```

Please take a look at [SetUnifiedGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/users-and-groups/set-unifiedgroup?view=exchange-ps) for more information.

Comment: This [Uservoice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/35391220-make-unifiedgroupwelcomemessageenabled-work-for-te) may be related. The newly added user still gets a Teams-specific Mail if he is added via the Teams Client. This setting only prevents the Group Mail (as I said in the original Post, you get two mails without this setting). This seems to be the same as "WelcomeEmailDisabled" when creating the Group with Graph.